# Keepass masterkey isn't recognized after a reinstall

Tags: keepass

My password hasn't changed and I didn't fo rget it. I am 100% sure I know the password. Nevertheless after a reinstall of the OS and a reinstall of Keepass I get the message that I use the wrong password, but I am very sure I use the exact password from before the reinstall. What can I do to reload the database?

Comment: Any chance you have a different keyboard layout (or some "international" behaviour with [dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)) and hence are actually typing something different? And what does "reloading the database" mean to you? (I guess it does not imply resetting the password, as like you're already read [here](http://superuser.com/questions/80372/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-a-lost-forgotten-keepass-password/751890#751890) there is no way to retrieve a lost password.)

Comment: Did you only use a master password or did you also use the windows user account as a lock?

Answer (score 3):

I got this kind of issue upgrading keepass version years ago. Be sure that you use the same version than before.

Comment: @The_only_one : Can you deal with your keepass trouble ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you used a second factor, like a *key file* that KeePass remembered and picked automatically.

A new installation might lack that information, and (more fatally) the key file itself, maybe.

If you used and lost a key file, you are lost, too.